# WordPress + PHP - How can I find out whether there are less paragraphs in a record?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this (tortured) script:

```
    /*-----------------------------  3 ---------------------------*/
 $paragraphAfter3 = 3;

*------------------------  WIDGET 3 ----------------------------*/
//Widget Area
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets_google-ads-3' );
function register_my_widgets_main_google_ads_3(){
  register_sidebar( array(
    /* 'name'          => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ), */
    'name'          => 'My code 3',
    /* 'id'            => "sidebar-$i", */
    'id'            => 'google-ads-3',
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>\n",
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="google-ads-3 widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => "</h2>\n",
  ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets_main_google_ads_3' );


/*  function GoogleADS1(){
  if ( function_exists('register_my_widgets_google-ads-1') )
    dynamic_sidebar(google-ads-1);
};  */


add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_content_google_ads_3' );

function wpse_content_google_ads_3( $content ) {
if( !is_single() )
return $content;
/*Number paragraf*/
/* $paragraphAfter = 3; //number of paragraph */

global $paragraphAfter3;
$paragraphAfter = $paragraphAfter3; //number of paragraph
$content = explode ( "</p>", $content );
$new_content = '';
for ( $a = 0; 
    $a < count ( $content ); 
    $a ++ ) {
if ( $a == $paragraphAfter ) {
  ob_start();
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'google-ads-3' ) ) :
   dynamic_sidebar( 'google-ads-3' ); 
else :
   echo '<span></span>';
endif;
$result = ob_get_clean();

$new_content .= $result ;
}
  elseif ($a != $paragraphAfter) {
    $new_content .=  '';
}
$new_content .= $content[$a] . "</p>";
}
return $new_content;
}
```

This script inserts the contents of the widget through a certain number of paragraphs, and works well. But if there are fewer paragraphs on the page. He then glues the contents of the Widgets into a footer.
How to achieve that it would not display the widget if there are fewer paragraphs in the post than indicated in it?

Comment: Note that SO operates exclusively in English, please delete this question.

Comment: For an example, install this plugin on WP, and you will see the result: goo.gl/Dmuk9j

Comment: @jonrsharp  Thank you, I'm new here. And I'm sorry for my English (I use Google translator)

Comment: I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exploding the contents using `$content = explode ( "</p>", $content );`, the last part of loop is not going to have the

tag, so you might as well loop until the 2nd last value only like this:

```
for ( $a = 0; $a < count ( $content )-1;  $a ++ ) //**Notice - 1 here**
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

BUt my huncha is your code is messing up the DOM and thats why the results of the widgets are moving to the footer. Once case where I see this happening is if `$paragraphAfter = 0`. IN this case the result of the widget is added **before** the first part of `content` which might mess up the DOM and make this widget show up in the footer.